# ¿Cómo activar botón con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo sería la forma para activar el botón "btn" , ya que sólo me activa el primer botón de la tabla?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Gestion.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>

    <style>
        *, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#target td {
  /* para centrado vertical de contenido */
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#target tr > *:nth-child(4) {
    display: none;
}

    </style>

    <script>

        function add(button) {
            var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
            var cells = row.querySelectorAll('td:not(:last-of-type)');
            button.disabled = true;
            addToCartTable(cells);

        }

        function remove() {

            var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            document.querySelector('#target tbody')
                          .removeChild(row);
            var celda = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
            var botones = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
            $('#source tr').each(function () {

                var pk = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();
                if (pk == celda) {
                    //alert($(this).find("td").eq(4).toString);

                    var botones = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
                    for (var i = 0; i < botones.length; i++) {
                        botones[i].addEventListener('click', (function (i) {
                            return function () {
                                this.disable = false;
                            };
                        })(i), false);
                    }
                }
            })
        };



        function addToCartTable(cells) {
            var registro = cells[0].innerText;
            var name = cells[2].innerText;
            var price = cells[3].innerText;

            var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
            newRow.setAttribute('data-price', price.substring(0));

            newRow.appendChild(createCell(registro));
            newRow.appendChild(createCell(name));
            newRow.appendChild(createCell(price));
            newRow.appendChild(createCell('1'));
            newRow.appendChild(createCell(price));

            var cellInputQty = createCell();
            cellInputQty.appendChild(createInputQty());
            newRow.appendChild(cellInputQty);

            var cellRemoveBtn = createCell();
            cellRemoveBtn.appendChild(createRemoveBtn())
            newRow.appendChild(cellRemoveBtn);

            document.querySelector('#target tbody').appendChild(newRow);
        }

        function createInputQty() {
            var inputQty = document.createElement('input');
            inputQty.type = 'number';
            inputQty.required = 'true';
            inputQty.className = 'form-control'
            inputQty.min = 1; // mínimo un producto
            inputQty.onchange = onQtyChange;
            inputQty.value = 0;
            return inputQty;
        }

        function createRemoveBtn() {
            var btnRemove = document.createElement('button');
            btnRemove.className = 'btn btn-xs btn-danger';
            btnRemove.onclick = remove;
            btnRemove.innerText = 'Eliminar';
            return btnRemove;
        }

        function createCell(text) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            if (text) {
                td.innerText = text;
            }
            return td;
        }

        function onQtyChange(e) {
            var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            var cellPrice = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(3)');
            var prevPrice = Number(row.getAttribute('data-price'));
            var newQty = Number(this.value);
            var total = prevPrice * newQty;

            var QtyValue = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(4)');
            QtyValue.innerText = newQty;
            cellPrice.innerText = '$' + total;
            //document.getElementById('run').disabled = false;
            if (QtyValue > 0) {
                document.getElementById('run').disabled = false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('run').disabled = true;
            }
        }

    </script>
     <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.adt.com.ar/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://lightswitch05.github.io/table-to-json/javascripts/jquery.tabletojson.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:Literal ID="ltRuta" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

    <div class="table-responsive">




      <asp:Repeater ID="rpProductos" runat="server">
          <HeaderTemplate>
              <table id="source" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>#</th>
                      <th>Código</th>
                      <th>Nombre</th>
                      <th>Precio</th>
                      <th>Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
          </HeaderTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
              <tr>
                  <td><%# Eval("registro") %></td>
                  <td><%# Eval("codigo") %></td>
                  <td><%# Eval("nombre") %></td>
                  <td><%# Eval("valor") %></td>
                  <td>
                    <button onclick="add(this)" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="btn">
                      Agregar
                    </button>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterTemplate>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
          </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>


</div>
 <button id="run" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="target" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Código</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
      <th>qty</th>
      <th>unit</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
    </form>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function createFormData(info) {
            jsonObject = {};
            var datos = 'datos';
            jsonObject[datos] = info;
            return jsonObject;
        }



        $('#run').click(function () {

            var table = $('#target').tableToJSON();
            console.log(JSON.stringify(createFormData(table)));
            console.log('se inicia el ajax');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/WebMethod.aspx/SendMail",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ datos: JSON.stringify(createFormData(table)) }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });
                alert(JSON.stringify(table));
        });

        function OnSuccess(response) {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            //alert(response.d);
            if (response.d == "True") {
                alert('Email Enviado Correctamente');


                //window.top.location.href = '/gracias-por-contactarnos/';
            } else {
                alert('Fallo en envio');



            }

        }


</script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById('run').disabled = true;
        });
    </script>
<%--     <script>

         $(document).ready(function () {
             document.getElementById('run').disabled = true;
            $('#source').DataTable({
                "language": {
                    "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
                    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                    "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                    "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                    "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                    "sInfoPostFix": "",
                    "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                    "sUrl": "",
                    "sInfoThousands": ",",
                    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sFirst": "Primero",
                        "sLast": "Último",
                        "sNext": "Siguiente",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                    },
                    "oAria": {
                        "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>--%>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

De [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/id)

> El [atributo global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) **id** define un identificador único (ID) el cual no debe repetirse en todo el documento.

En otras palabras, el problema se debe a que tu código está usando un ID más de una vez. En primer lugar, usa ID's distintos para cada botón, digamos `btn1` y `btn2` en segundo, para activarlos, usa

```
document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = false; // habilitar
document.getElementById("btn2").disabled = false; // habilitar
```

Cabe mencionar que en [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document) se listan hay otras formas, tales como

```
document.getElementById()
document.getElementsByClassName()
document.getElementsByName()
document.getElementsByTagName()
document.getElementsByTagNameNS()
```

Answer (score 1):

Noto que estás usando `getElementById`, deberías asignarle una clase 'btn' a cada botón y luego utilizar `getElementByClassName` así:

```
var botones = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(botones, function(boton) {
    boton.disabled = false;
});
```

O con Jquery:

```
$(".btn").prop('disabled', false);
```

El código de arriba claramente es figurativo, en tu caso deberías modificar la clase por la que vos quieras.

En el caso de que quieras restringir la función solo al botón que fue clickeado podrías utilizar la siguiente función:

```
var botones = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

for (var i = 0; i < botones.length; i++) {
    botones[i].addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
        return function() {
            this.disable = false;
        };
    })(i), false);
}​
```

Usando Jquery:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
});
```

**Update:**

Cuando clickeas el botón "source" como dices en el comentario se llama a la función `add()` que deshabilita dicho botón y agrega un botón que al ser clickeado llama a `remove()`, lo que puedes hacer es agregar esta línea a dicha función para que vuelva a habilitar el "source":

```
$("#btn").prop('disabled', false);
```

Nota: Te recomiendo cambiar ese id por uno más propicio como `btnAgregar` solo por poner un ejemplo, para evitar equivocaciones con la clase `btn` que le agregaste a todos los botones.

Espero haberte sido de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias, el problema es que me activa todos los botones de la tabla,

Comment: Creí que eso era lo que buscaba, podría ampliar la pregunta especificando cuales botones quiere que se activen y cuales no, por favor?

Comment: Son los botones creados de forma dinamica. Si elimino algo de una segunda tabla el botón se vuelve habilitar. Agregué código.

Comment: Ahí edité la pregunta para el caso en el que solo se quiera habilitar el fue clickeado

Comment: Hola, en la función Remove() agregué como quedarí el código, sin embargo no logro hacer que funcione. Alguna idea?

Comment: Cuál es el error que te arroja? Te recomiendo poner más código, el que sea necesario para que entendamos cual de los botones tendrían que habilitarse y como se generan

Comment: agregue todo el codigo.

Comment: Probaste agregando `button.disabled = false` al final de `add()`?

Comment: Cuando llamo a la 'function add(button)' el boton generado en la tabla [source] se debe deshabilitar. Cuando presiono el botón creado en la tabla [target] el boton de la tabla [source] se debe volver habilitar

Comment: Ahí edité la respuesta. Te recomiendo para la próxima pregunta que hagas que todo lo que me detallaste en los comentarios lo pongas en la pregunta para que se entienda mucho mejor y le sea mas fácil a los usuarios ayudarte. Saludos!

Comment: No hay caso ni siquiera entra a  `$('#source tr').each(function () {`

Comment: Eso quizás es motivo para otra pregunta colega, sinceramente ya no tengo idea en que podría ayudarte, no encuentro motivos así de vista :S

Comment: OK, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: De nada colega, disculpas por no haber sido de mayor utilidad